# Why Anchor tag is not working after removing #

Tags: c#, html, sitecore

I am developing sitecore application, i am creating path of item dynamically because of some business logic. When I give

```
 href= path+'#'+item name
```

then it's working but its showing on URL and my client don't want that. So I change logic and replace # with / . But I when click to anchor it's not redirecting. Why it so..

Answer (score 4):

An anchor tag refers to a specific element within a web-page. The # is selecting the item by id, this tells the browser to load the URL then go to the item with the id specified `#item-name`. Therefore replacing the # with anything else will not work as it is the selector.

You will need to use URL Masking if you want the # to not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably some good accessibility reasons to keep the "#anchor" visible in the browser URL bar...

... but, for aesthetic reasons, if you wish to eliminate that, but still have the same functionality (ie navigating to different parts of a single webpage), then you could explore using Javascript to do the same thing. If done correctly, you can interact with a page and the URL will never change.

If you use a JS library for this ([for example](https://www.google.ca/search?q=jquery%20scrollTo&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=XherWM-YFom4jwTwgKiACg)), then you can explore softer transitions between page locations, rather than a quick cut jump.